# Are there any better (perhaps business-oriented) alternatives to "pitting against" for this situation?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, idioms, business-language

Recently a colleague demonstrated a shared Microsoft OneNote notebook in which he and other members of his team posted their weekly accomplishments in sort of bulleted lists. The idea was that they could monitor one another's bandwidth so they could assist one another. I saw it differently however: to me it seemed that it sort of pitted them against one another to see who could have more bullets on their list of accomplishments.

Is there any better term than "pitted against" to describe this method of trying to motivate someone by guilt or by always trying not to seem the team's weakest link? It isn't quite the stick, but it definitely isn't the carrot.

Comment: Sometimes the competition is definitely *the stick*. In *Glengarry Glen Ross*, all salesmen were required to compete for top sales. All but the top two were to be fired.

Comment: Good question! I feel there *must* be at least one single-word verb with this *set in conflict or rivalry against another* sense, but offhand I just can't think of one. Btw - I suppose the usage *to pit against* is a metaphoric reference to putting dogs, bears, etc., in a *fighting pit*, but I don't know.

Comment: They actually are asked 'to confront' each other and see who is doing better.

Comment: Off-topic, but to make it fair, the bulleted items should also be weighted for degree of usefulness.  That would make the number of listed items a little less relevant.

Comment: @Josh61: True, but if you *confront two employees*, the implication  is there's a conflict between *you* on one side, and *both of them* on the other.

Comment: I don't see it as a confrontation between the employees, @Josh61, but each employee is definitely confronted by the others' lists.

Comment: Thanks @Josh61 I feel like, yes, there is implied confrontation because they're definitely all fighting for praise in a sense. But it isn't really like dogs fighting in any aggressive capacity. It's like a sort of a battle to see who can be more professionally obsequious. Sort of.

Comment: OED has ***competize*** - but that's obsolete, and was always extremely rare.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why are all the good ones always so obscure?

Comment: @thomas: I really don't know! But thinking about it, I suppose those Anglophones who still organise dog fights might quite reasonably say *"We fight dogs in the abandoned warehouse on Friday nights"* (as in *make the dogs fight **each other***, rather than ***us** fighting against the dogs*). And perhaps there's still a really common verb for this that just hasn't come to mind yet.

Comment: Using productivity, I'll make something up. A lot of people won't think it's a word, but it really is. *Competitionize*. Yeah, what they have there is a good old *competitionization*. That's too new to be obsolete, like Fumblefinger's obsolete *competize*, so I think it will do the trick.

Comment: Thinking about it again, I realise that even ***pit*** doesn't meet the criteria I had in mind when I first read this question. You can't just say *"These weekly lists will **pit** the staff"* without adding *"...against each other"*. And all the alternatives seem to require some kind of preposition - such as *"...will incite rivalry **among** the staff"*. I'm starting to feel maybe there is no transitive verb suitable for the construction *"These weekly lists will XXXXX the staff"*, where *XXXXX = foster competitiveness within [some group with the syntactic role of **direct object**]*.

Answer (score 2):

I think to say they are *vying with* each other rather than being *pitted against* each other would suggest more of a co-operative business relationship. Competing within the same team but not in conflict.

Comment: I like this observation.

Answer (score 2):

If the point you want to make is that this motivation method is going to cause employees to waste time inventing and promoting minor or irrelevant accomplishments as successes on a competitive weekly list, you might frame the problem as "**creating an arms race for bullet points**."

Comment: I know it is sort of in opposition to my original intent behind posting the question, but this is so clever I'd feel sort of guilty stealing it :)

Comment: But I think I will.

Answer (score 1):

The term *friendly [rivalry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rivalry)* is sometimes used to describe this situation.

> Competition for the same objective or for superiority in the same field [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Similarly the phrase *[dueling](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/duel) [somethings]* is often used to convey a competition between two similarly matched practitioners of the [something] skill.

> [MAINLY JOURNALISM] a close competition between two people or teams [*Macmillan*]

*[Dueling Banjos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dueling_Banjos)*, a popular song from the movie *Deliverance*, is a prime example, but a search for *dueling* provides many other examples.

If the rankings are publicly displayed, they could be said to be on a *[leaderboard](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leaderboard)*.

> a large board for displaying the ranking of the leaders in a competitive event (as a golf tournament) [*Merriam-Webster*]